# How to use MAAS to render

Tags: maas, cluster

I want to build a cluster for rendering my projects i do in Blender 3D. I do not want to use the network render addon because it is a little bit boring and it also can not support single image. So I want to render via the machines that Maas starts and installs..

Is Ubuntu MAAS the right tool for that?
And how do I have to set it up?

How can I do that?

Comment: Rewrote to a clear question so it does not get closed. Partly had to guess the original meaning. If I guessed wrong, please edit to describe in more detail. Also, it may help if you say what/in which way you want to render; In the way you use the word, it does not mean much more than "calcuate some result".

Comment: Much better, thanks! Can you define "boring", so a solution has a chance to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

*This is answering the question independent of Blender 3D, assuming  rendering in general.

(The answer was started before an edit of the question adding the reference to Blender 3D)*

MAAS is a system to manage a cluster in a dynamic way.

It is helpful if you often change 
your cluster hardware,  or the services deployed on it, or the instances running on it.

For the problem you are solving, that feature set seems to be not very relevant:

I assume you want to build one cluster. That will consist of a fixed set of rougly uniform hardware nodes, that may change infrequently. You want to run one parallel application software on it, so you require one instance of a render service on each node.

The tasks where MAAS could help are the initial setup of the nodes, the deployment of the render service, and changing the cluster, like when adding another node.
But in these tasks, there is neither much repetition, nor much dynamism - the areas where MAAS is powerful.

Because of that, I think the overhead of using MAAS is probably larger than the advantages for your task.

It seems to make more sense to directly set up just the cluster; This gives you the freedom to choose the kind of cluster software based on the needs of your application.

Comment: So what do you exactly suggest?

Comment: I suggest to not use MAAS, but something else.